# CommandBar overflow in UWP app - can it be scrollable?

Tags: xaml, scroll, uwp, overflow, commandbar

### Background

I am developing a UWP app, which is being designed for mobile, desktop etc.

I am having a bit of difficulty with the `CommandBar` on certain pages - specifically on a phone (but this may also apply to a smaller desktop window).

---

### Issue

Where I require quite a few `AppBarButton`s on the `CommandBar`, sometimes it overflows and I am unable to see/access the hidden buttons.

Here is a sample screenshot where you can see that the "Documents" label is being cut off. There is also another button (which cannot be seen/accessed) which I guess you would say is "underneath" the `...` button:

[image: sample commandbar overflow screenshot]

---

### XAML

*Shortened for brevity (nothing special/out of the ordinary here)*

```
<CommandBar>
    <!-- Secondary Commands -->
    <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
                      Icon="Refresh" Label="Refresh"/>
        <AppBarButton Command="{Binding AddToLibraryCommand}"
                      Icon="Save" Label="Add to Library"/>
    </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

    <!-- Primary Commands -->
    <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton Command="{Binding CompleteFormCommand}"
                      Icon="Paste" Label="Complete a Form" />
        <AppBarSeparator />
        <AppBarButton Command="{Binding ViewPeopleCommand}"
                      Icon="People" Label="People" />
        <AppBarButton Command="{Binding ViewPropertiesCommand}"
                      Icon="Home" Label="Properties" />
        <AppBarButton Command="{Binding ViewDocumentsCommand}"
                      Icon="Folder" Label="Documents" />
        <AppBarSeparator />
        <AppBarButton Command="{Binding ViewMapCommand}"
                      Icon="Map" Label="Map" />
    </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
</CommandBar>
```

---

### What I need

I still need the other `AppBarButton`s to be accessible by the user.

The amount of buttons on each `CommandBar` can vary - sometimes they fit fine, some have 1 (like the example) hidden, others have 2 or 3 hidden.

I am thinking that (surely, somehow) it might be possible somehow to allow horizontal scrolling in order to access the other buttons?

---

### What I have tried

I have resorted to moving some of the non-essential commands to the `CommandBar.SecondaryCommands`, to free up some space; as can be seen in the screenshot/XAML above - however, the main problem is still apparent.

There is no `ScrollViewer` attached property, and trying to nest the `AppBarButton`s inside one naturally throws me a compiler error:

> Invalid type: expected types are `IObservableVector<ICommandBarElement>` or `ICommandBarElement`, actual type is `ScrollViewer`.

I have searched the Web far and wide for answers to see if it is possible, and it doesn't appear there is much literature (or any similar StackOverflow answers) on how I can go about solving this issue.

---

All advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Interested to see why, nearly 4 years later, this gets a downvote with constructive comment? What about the question wasn't very good? -- I welcome any suggestions on how I can improve it

Answer (score 0):

As for me, it is not pretty good UX behavior, but you can override `Style` for `CommandBar` and wrap primary `ItemsControl` into `ScrollViewer`.

Find the default style and find the `PrimaryItemsControl` and replace to:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="PrimaryItemsControl"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeMinHeight}"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

After that don't forget apply new style for `CommandBar`:

```
<CommandBar Style="{StaticResource ScrollablePrimaryComamndCommandBar}">
```

*P.S.* [full xaml on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/f6Fq7FSu)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Andrii - I will see if I can give this a try. When you say *"...not pretty good UX behavior..."*, what do you mean? The general idea of a scrollable `CommandBar`; or the solution you have posted?

Comment: @GeoffJames for scrollable `CommandBar`, not for my solution :)

Comment: Andrii -- no worries. I wasn't doubting the solution, just thought I'd clarify what you meant. I'll let you know how I get on :) Thanks again

Comment: @GeoffJames I've updated an aswer, posted full xaml on pastebin